# Android RAM usage goes up when loading a map in the webview

Tags: android, memory, webview

I have a simple application which loads a google map and lets the user choose a location. What I've observed is that when this webview loads up, the RAM usage goes up to 40 MB from ~4 MB.

Is the webview caching the map in the RAM? Is this normal? Does webview cache the pages?

Even after I leave the webview, the RAM usage is still at ~40 MB, I tried webview.destroy() but it does not release any memory.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This should be normal.

RAM will be freed after garbage collector will get rid of destroyed stuff, but you can't control this though.

Comment: But I'm worried it might be a problem on devices with less RAM. Any possible way to handle this?

Comment: According to your post it's a webview RAM usage, not yours. And yes, my device has 684 MB. Does this still concern you?